# Как сделать отображение шрифта иконок кросс-браузерно?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать отображение шрифта иконок кросс-браузерно?

Сайт на Wordpress, переделываю личный кабинет Woocommerce. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, использую встроенные в WP иконки dashicons.

Google Chrome:
[image: Google Chrome]

Opera:
[image: Opera]

EDGE:
[image: EDGE]

Comment: конвертируйте шрифт в разные форматы.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный не ужели сам WordPress это не делает, это шрифт который идет с WP?

Comment: я не знаю что под капотом. посмотрите в настройках какие форматы подключены, или через отладку в браузере. слишком мало информации в вопросе. просто посоветовал обратить на это внимание. может они просто вовсе не подключены в других браузера из-за ошибке в подключении.

Comment: Скорее всего ты неправильно подключил дашиконы. Или они перебиваются другими. Если то вообще дашиконы. Дашиконовская корзина выглядит по другому. https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#trash

Comment: @SeVlad такая же это корзина, 100% dashicons, просто скриншот с машины, где отключено сглаживание шрифтов

Comment: Вы их точно не переопределили? посмотрите в инспекторе кода в опере, там dashicons стоит? Зайдите в инкогнито в хроме, там иконки отображаются?